# How to move the common code to one rails engine which is commonly shared by other engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

Will try to explain as clear as possible as it may not be easy put in a post.  In our `rails 3.2 app` (which is consists of a bunch of `rails engine`), `search` is standardized for every  `engine` in engine's `application controller` with `views` under `/views`. To add search to a `rails engine`, just need to add the same action definition code to `engine's application_controller` and drop the `views` to /views. Since the `search` code is exactly the same for every engine, we are thinking to move the code to `rail engine` `common` which is commonly shared by every other engines.

We probably can not move all the code to `engine common` because of the structure. Is there a way we can move the view and action code to `engine common` and calling the code from other `engines`? So there is only one copy of the code and every other `engines` are just calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a new engine called `common` (other big projects like eg. [Spree](http://github.com/spree/spree) uses `core`).

## Search Engine

However I think it would be even better to create a dedicated `search` engine. The engine should then have all controller related code in module inside the search engine like this:

*in search/lib/search/search_helpers.rb*

```
module Search
  module SearchHelpers
    # Search related code
  end
end
```

*in search/lib/search.rb*

```
# Add this line to require the new module, and make it accessible in your application
require 'search/search_helpers.rb'
...
```

Then add the search engine as a dependency on all engines where you want this search functionality, and include the module in your application controller. So if you have a engine called `frontend` should you have something like this:

*in frontend/frontend.gemspec*

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name         = "frontend"
  ...

  s.add_dependency "search"
end
```

*in frontend/Gemfile*

```
# You will need to add the engine to the gemfile as well, to specify the path.
gem 'search', path: '../search'
```

*in frontend/app/controllers/frontend/application_controller.rb*

```
module Frontend
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include Search::SearchHelpers
  end
end
```

## Notes

### BaseController

Commonly do you call the "application controllers" of engines for "base controllers" and let them inherit from your unique `ApplicationController` like this:

*in frontend/app/controllers/frontend/application_controller.rb*

```
module Frontend
  class BaseController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

### SearchController

I would recommend that you created a `SearchController` instead of including this behaviour in each engines controllers.

So you had something like this:

*in search/app/controllers/search/search_controller.rb*

```
module Search
  class SearchController < ApplicationController
    ...
  end
end
```

*in search/frontend/config/routes.rb*

```
mount Search::Engine, at: "/search"
```

Hope this helps! Please comment if their is anything you are unsure about :)!

Comment: Interesting idea! Why gem search needs to be added to both Gemfile and gemspec of the engine frontend (for example)? According to rails 3.2, a gem only needs to be added to gemspec if it is required by the engine.

Comment: I suppose search controller is in search engine and there are search actions in search controller. In engine frontend's routes.rb, do we still need to declare search action for the resource which will have search feature?

Comment: A engine shouldn't have a gemfile, only for development. However because the `search` engine doesn't exists on rubygems.org, and you can't specify paths in gemspec (not to my knowledge at least), do you need this little "hack" :)

Comment: Yes the search controller would be in the search engine. It's not sure it's the best solution, that depends on your setup. Sometimes it's more complex to have one SearchController if that should be responsible for searching several different models, in different ways. You should not do both though, either include a module or create one (or more) search controllers :)

Comment: Where to declare the search action for the resource? It seems that the declaration has to be in model (to be searched) itself.

Comment: Since search engine is not on rubygems.org, then it probably does not help adding s.add_dependency in gemspec.

Comment: Are the views for the search under app/views/ in search engine? It seems that the views need to be in search engine. Then how to setup route to point to the views in search engine?

Comment: You can read about routes in engines here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes or here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html or watch this RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines

Comment: Can you be more specific? We have read those documents many times.

Comment: When you "install" your search engine into your another engine, or application then you need to add this to your engine/application's route file `mount Search::Engine => "/search"`. Now all routes defined in the search engine would be available under the `/search` path prefix.